# I have removed controller name using codeigniter router. Now how to get controller name?

Tags: codeigniter

```
$route['about'] = 'core/about';
$route['blog'] = 'core/blog';
$route['press'] = 'core/press';
```

In URL it's showing abc.com/about

How can I get controller name from url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$this->router->fetch_class();
$this->router->fetch_method();
```

Use `fetch_class` to get current controller name and use `fetch_method` to get the current function name in your relevant controller. 
Or you can simply do this using core PHP

```
echo __CLASS__;
```

To do the same thing in codeigniter:

```
echo $this->router->class;
```

Comment: Not working as $this->router->fetch_class(); will return the first uri segment like $this->uri->segment(1); 
But i would like to get the controller name "core" which is hidden using routes.php.

Answer (score 2):

if your url helper is auto loaded from autoload.php in config then you can access your controller as

```
$this->uri->segment(1);
```

For further Learning [Codeigniter URLS](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html?highlight=uri)